# Sony QX100 return 403 error for supported methods

Tags: android, sony-camera-api

I am trying to set the Exposure mode and Focus mode for my QX100 device. Each time I make the API call I get a 403 error. However, these two methods `setExposureMode` and `setFocusMode` are supported by the QX100 as it clearly states in the API docs. In addition, I can set the focus mode through Playmemories. This same problem also occurs with `setBeepMode`, which is also supported. Any ideas about why this could be occurring?

There are some supported methods that are working, such as `actTakePicture` and `setPostviewImageSize`

An example call:

```
 public JSONObject setFocusMode() throws IOException {
    String service = "camera";
    try {
        JSONObject requestJson =
                new JSONObject().put("method", "setFocusMode").put("params", new JSONArray().put("MF")) //
                        .put("id", id()).put("version", "1.0");
        String url = findActionListUrl(service) + "/" + service;

        log("Request:  " + requestJson.toString());
        JSONObject responseJson = SimpleHttpClient.httpPost(url, requestJson, null);
        log("Response: " + responseJson.toString());

        return responseJson;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your QX100 updated to the latest firmware? On old one, most of APIs are restricted.

Or they may be temporary disabled. You can use `getAvailableApiList` to know that.